# Is there an easy way to create a list of these elements so I can loop through the list and click?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to create a list of 'Yes' buttons so I can loop through the list and click the 'Yes' button instead of targetting them individually.

I'm getting an incorrect count when I try to add them to the list because I'm not sure how to ignore the empty columns within each section and each section has a different number of buttons.

I came close to solving this by using two for loops but I'm not sure how to deal with the empty columns so it messes my loop up.

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated. I'm quite new to the framework so learning how to solve something like this would be great for my development. I thought I could just search for all buttons and loop through them using indexing but that didn't seem to work:

```
//button[contains (text(), 'Yes')][x]
```

Here's [a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpnzE.jpg)!

```
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-heading">Section 1</h2>
    <div class="section-content">
        <div class="grid group">
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-heading">Section 1</h2>
    <div class="section-content">
        <div class="grid group">
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2">
                <div id="button-group">
                    <button>No</button>
                    <button>Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid group">
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid group">
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid group">
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2">
                <div id="button-group">
                    <button>No</button>
                    <button>Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid col span 1_of_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please `edit` your post and include the example inline as text. External links are discouraged as they can go out of date and the point of this forum is to provide a database of questions and answers for users now and in the future, and the image is hard to work with for people who want to try it out and test a solution. See [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the Driver.FindElements  method to get the list of button for example:

```
var ListButton =Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[contains (text(), 'Yes')]"));

    foreach(var Actualbutton in ListButton )
    {
        if ( Actualbutton.Displayed && Actualbutton.Enabled )
        {
            Actualbutton.Click();
        }
    }
```

Note: if the site is refreshed after you click the button you will need to refresh the list, otherwise you will receive exception of `reference to object not established as an instance of an object`

in that case you can do something like this:

```
//collect list of buttonyes
 var ListButton =Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[contains (text(), 'Yes')]"));

    for(int i=0 ;i<ListButton.Count ;i++ )
    {
        if(ListButton[i].Enabled &&ListButton[i].Displayed )
        {
            ListButton[i].Click ( );
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep ( 2000 );
        }         
        ListButton=Driver.FindElements ( By.XPath ( "//button[contains (text(), 'Yes')]" ) );
    }
```

Comment: This resolved my problem. I was able to understand where I was going wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can use a querySelector:
`document.querySelectorAll(".grid > .grid > #button-group > button")` to select all the buttons, then filter out all the buttons that are "No", and then you have your list of buttons.

I'm not super familair with C# Selenium but here is an example of what it might look like:

```cs
IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var elements = js.ExecuteScript<Array<IWebElement>>("document.querySelectorAll('.grid > .grid > #button-group > button')");
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. Thank you, I'll give this a try.